# How to install Lagrange in Cygwin?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, cygwin, c++

I need to install a script for biogeographical analyses in Windows XP using Cygwin. The program is named [Lagrange](http://code.google.com/p/lagrange) and is written in C++. It actually comes with instructions to install in Linux and Mac OS X, but as I know almost nothing of the languages used. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the source and compile it yourself.

This is not an easy task, Cygwin has a few special quirks that *may* need source alterations (especially as the source is still in beta).

If using the Python version is not an option may I suggest that you try installing it in a virtualized Linux machine *(for example [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/))*. Once you are able to install it from source there, you can try on Cygwin.